# SSIS package runs fine in VSTS 2019 but not in SQL Server 2017 via SQL Agent or DTEXEC

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-agent-job

I have a very basic SSIS package with one SQL Task. It works fine in Visual Studio 2019 but doesn't run in SSMS or via DTEXEC on the server.

I have my package set to EncrptSensitiveWithPassword. I have developed the package locally, with my machine user.

To deploy, I copied the DTSX onto the server and used a sysadmin account to set up a sql agent job to run it from the file system.

With my package target server set correctly to 2017 I get:

> Executed as user: NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 13.0.4574.0 for 64-bit  Copyright (C)
>   2016 Microsoft.  All rights reserved.    Started:  8:54:27 AM  Error:
>   2019-06-27 08:54:27.23     Code: 0xC0010018     Source: Package_v2
>   Description: **Error loading value DTS:ConnectionManagers
>   xmlns:DTS="www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts"DTS:ConnectionManager
>   DTS:refId="Package.ConnectionManagers[Target DB]" 
>   DTS:CreationName="OLEDB"
>   DTS:DTSID="{7DB8E823-90A7-499C-85AF-8304FAC5E575}"
>   DTS:ObjectName="Target DB"DTS:ObjectD" from node
>   "DTS:ConnectionManagers"**.  End  Error  Could not load package
>   "F:\SSIS\Data Warehouse Import\Package_v2.dtsx" because of error
>   0xC0010014.   Description: The package failed to load due to error
>   0xC0010014 "One or more error occurred. There should be more specific
>   errors preceding this one that explains the details of the errors. 
>   This message is used as a return value from functions that encounter
>   errors.". This occurs when CPackage::LoadFromXML fails.   Source:
>   Package_v2  Started:  8:54:27 AM  Finished: 8:54:27 AM  Elapsed: 
>   0.079 seconds.  The package could not be loaded.  The step failed.

Changing the target SQL Server to 2016 or prior (incorrect) gives me a database connection timeout. Switching from 64 to 32 bit makes no difference (Both my machine and the server are 64-bit anyway).

Google has been pretty unhelpful. I am at my wits end.

Comment: The error  states *"There should be more specific errors preceding this one that explains the details of the errors."* but you haven't included those specific errors.

Comment: Also why use the File System deployment method? The SSIS Catalog is way better. Did you remove the password from the dtsx before you deployed it?

Comment: Hi Larnu. I did manage to deploy it into my Integration Services Catalogs folder in SSMS but I get a "error has occurred establishing a connection to SQL server" error, which is odd. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. The connection string looks fine. As regards the SQL Agent error, I've given you the full text from the log. No I didn't remove the password from the DTSX before deployment. Should I have done?

Comment: You would need to if you if you aren't letting SQL Server know what the password is (honestly, I haven't used the package deployment method in almost 7 years now, so I can't really remember the specifics). Considering that the server is stating it can't read the package, this strongly suggests it's because the package is encrypted and couldn't be decrypted by the SQL Server (because it's passworded). Getting SSISDB to work would seem like the better option here, in my view though, as the deployment removes to protection in the project, and encrypts it within SQL Server based a generated key.

Comment: I was deploying to 2017 when it should have been 2016. I have corrected this. Now I get the "A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible" error both when executing via the file system SQL Agent job and the Integration Services Catalogs imported package.

Comment: I assume that's error occurs when running a Execute T-SQL task, or data flow? you'll need to debug those; the logs from SSISDB are very verbose so they'll give you a lot of detail.

Comment: yes, the lack of database connection occurs for both SQL tasks and data flow tasks. I have added a few of each to my package and now get a series of "The connection "{16854F56-19C3-458D-A749-B23F69D8C918}" is not found." errors, and right at the bottom, a "network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server".

Comment: Looking in the package XML for that connection, I see "connectionManagerID="{16854F56-19C3-458D-A749-B23F69D8C918}:invalid"
                      connectionManagerRefId="{16854F56-19C3-458D-A749-B23F69D8C918}:invalid"

Comment: Looks like you need to select/create your connection manager then, as what ever you were using previously has been deleted.

Answer (score 0):

With the 2016 release of the SSDT/Visual Studio tooling for BI projects, we have the ability to specify what version of SQL Server Integration Services packages the project should build. The default is to target the most recent version of SQL Server available.

When you deploy to the SSISDB, no checks are performed to verify the blob (ispac) we're stuffing into the database aligns with what the database can "speak." So, you built a project using the 2019 version of data tooling which assumes you're be deploying to a 2019 instance of sql server but you actually deploy to 2012 and hilarity ensues because the api for deployment is the same.

### How can I tell?

Open your SSIS project and if looks like this, it's targeting whatever VS thinks is current. This being a 2017 Visual Studio, it thinks SQL Server 2017 is what we're targeting.

[image]

Right click on the Project (SO_Trash in my example) and select Properties

In this window, expand the Configuration properties, select the General section and there in the Deployment Target Version, change the value of TargetServerVersion from SQL Server 2017 to SQL Server 2016

[image]

After clicking OK and confirming to Visual Studio that you want to reload your project, you should see something like this.

[image]

My project name now indicates the targeted version in parenthesis, thus SO_Trash (SQL Server 2016).

With all of your project bits matching what the server expects, deploy and then try running your package (or click the Validate button in SSMS but no one does that)

Comment: Hi, yes I already have it set to SQL Server 2016. That has got rid of my original error. As stated, I now have the ""A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server" error, suggesting either a permissions problem, which seems unlikely given my account has sysadmin rights, or the database password isn't carrying through somehow. I am using EncryptSensitiveWithPassword.

Comment: If your package is using Project level connection managers and you are trying to run the package outside of the ispac/project, it will cause issues. Could that be the next part of your issue?

Comment: No, I'm using a package connection manager only. Very straightforward. I have no issues connecting to SQL Server via SSMS, yet my SSIS package cannot connect even though it's running on the same server. To reiterate, I get the same error running the package in both SQL Agent and as a deployed package in Integration Services Catalogs.

Answer (score 0):

I got this message when I thought I knew the encrypt SSIS Package password but I didn't.   I checked with a colleague and he straightened me out.   You would think the error message would be "invalid password" or it would ask for the password a second time but it doesn't here.  Both VS 2017 ent and VS 2019 Pro showed this error message for an invalid ssis package password.  It's nasty.  It won't open the package and you think the package is so corrupted it won't open, but it's just the password.